# Again, variable in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, windows-7, vba

Using access 2010, windows 7, SQL Server

Can't get the hang of this. Have an SQL query that was generated in the qbe grid then put in VBA.  The version that runs has a literal  Transaction_Table.Account_Number and looks like:

```
"WHERE (((dbo_Transaction_Table.Sku)=""Transfer"") 
   AND ((dbo_Transaction_Table.Description) Like ""%TO%"") 
   AND ((dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number)=""655812""));"
```

But when I try to replace the literal with the contents of a text box :

```
"WHERE (((dbo_Transaction_Table.Description) Like ""%Transfer To%"") 
   AND ((dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number)=& Chr$(34) & Me.accntNo & Chr$(34)));"`
```

I get a syntax err (missing operator) in query expression

```
    (((dbo_Transaction_table.Description) like "%Transfer To%") 
And ((dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number)= & Chr$(34) & Me.accntNo & Chr$(34))))`
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're just missing quotes between the constant string and the injected values

```
"WHERE (((dbo_Transaction_Table.Description) Like ""%Transfer To%"") 
 AND ((dbo_Transaction_Table.Account_Number)=" & Chr$(34) & Me.accntNo & Chr$(34) & "));"
```

Although you might look into using parameters instead.  I'm not an expert on doing those from VBA but there should be plenty of examples out there.

Comment: It worked fine using your suggestion.  What do you mean by parameter query?  Is that creating a query on the fly?